# A different logic in ranking

Tags: php, mysql, logic

I have to find a solution for my ranking scenario.

Say i have 100 users in database. And there is 5 subject in another table. In my project users have an option to rate 1 to 5 rating of any subjects. Means a user should have 5 different rating for 5 different subject. I need to shoe on the front page which is the most rated subject on the landing page.

I have a plan like create a table like

```
table name: user_subject_rate

Structure

id: user_id: subject1: subject2: subject3: subject4: subject5

1     1           3       1          2        5         4
```

When i create a table like this what happens if a new subject come to rate?

Can anybody suggest me a solution for this? I am using mysql as database.

Comment: 1. See normalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise you to structure your tables like below.

**users**

```
user_id | name
-----------------
1         Michael
2         Andrew
3         Annie
```

**subjects**

```
subject_id | name
----------------------
1            Maths
2            English
3            Physics
4            Chemistry
5            Biology
```

**users_subjects_scores**

```
user_id | subject_id | score
----------------------------
1         1            5
1         2            5
1         3            4
1         4            2
1         5            3
2         1            1
2         2            2
2         3            4
2         4            5
2         5            3
```

Then you can work out the total score of each subject using this query:

```
SELECT
  name,
  COALESCE(SUM(score), 0) AS total_score
FROM
  subjects
LEFT JOIN
  users_subjects_scores USING (subject_id)
GROUP BY
  subject_id
ORDER BY
  SUM(score) DESC
```

Then adding a new subject is as simple as adding a new row to the `subjects` table.

You can see an [SQL fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb032/1).

Comment: Oh i forgot the basic relation. Now i got clear. Thanks MichaelRushton